# cv2 Multiple contours on the same object

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on the vehicle tracking script, and the contours of the cars are being drawn too many times.
The code I am running is a pretty simple comparison of frames and finding contours using the cv2 library.
I get too many contours from the cv2.findContours function, which gets over the cars.
Here is the sample output during the video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LLAG.jpg

Code:

```
last_frame = None
while cap.isOpened():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    # Processing of frames are done in gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # We blur it to minimize reaction to small details
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15, 15), 1)
    # Need to check if we have a lasqt_frame, if not get it
    if last_frame is None or last_frame.shape != gray.shape:
        last_frame = gray
        continue
    # Get the difference from last_frame
    delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(last_frame, gray)
    last_frame = gray
    # Have some threshold on what is enough movement
    thresh = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 33, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    # This dilates with two iterations
    kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=5)
    # Returns a list of objects
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # Converts it 
    contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
    lenn = len(contours)
    for cnt, contour in enumerate(contours):
        # Skip if contour is small (can be adjusted)
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 500:
            continue
        # Get's a bounding box and puts it on the frame
        # CAR BOUNDING BOX
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(frame, "CAR", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Car counting", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
```

I would like each of the bounding boxes to be one per vehicle.
What is the issue here?

Comment: Increase the kernel size for performing dilation

Comment: @Nemanja. Can you post original image?

Comment: @JeruLuke, thanks, this really helped out
toyotaSupra thanks for your interest