# OpenCV object detection multiple contours on the same object

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, noise-reduction

I'm trying to detect and track vehicles using frame differencing, but some vehicles are marked multiple times.

I've seen this post: [cv2 Multiple contours on the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71982455/cv2-multiple-contours-on-the-same-object) but I can't use dilate function because it makes noise horrible.

How can I mark each vehicle with a single rectangle until they leave the frame?

multiple frames screenshot:

[image: multiple frames screenshot]

difference between background and current frame:

[image: difference between background and current frame]

My code is here:

```
import cv2
import argparse
import numpy
import math
from tracker import *

from get_background import get_background


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='path to the input video',
                    required=True)
parser.add_argument('-c', '--consecutive-frames', default=4, type=int,
                    dest='consecutive_frames', help='path to the input video')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(args['input'])
# get the video frame height and width
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
save_name = f"outputs/{args['input'].split('/')[-1]}"
# define codec and create VideoWriter object
out = cv2.VideoWriter(
    save_name,
    cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 10,
    (frame_width, frame_height)
)

#object_detector = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=100, varThreshold=40)

# get the background model
background = get_background(args['input'])
# convert the background model to grayscale format
background = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frame_count = 0
consecutive_frame = args['consecutive_frames']

###########################################################################################

kernel_size = 3
gauss_img = cv2.bilateralFilter(background, 9, 300,300)
canny_img = cv2.Canny(gauss_img, 100, 200)
#canny_img = cv2.erode(canny_img, None, iterations=1)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny_img, rho=1, theta=math.pi / 180,
                        threshold=15,
                        minLineLength=50,
                        maxLineGap=5)
line_img = numpy.zeros((background.shape[0], background.shape[1], 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)

for points in lines:
    # Extracted points nested in the list
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = points[0]

    # Draw the lines joing the points
    # On the original image
    cv2.line(line_img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # Maintain a simples lookup list for points
    #lines_list.append([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])

cv2.imshow("lines", line_img)
#cv2.imshow("canny", canny_img)
if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    pass

###########################################################################################
# 24.08.2022 object tracking
tracker = EuclideanDistTracker() ###
detections = []

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        frame_count += 1
        orig_frames = []
        orig_frame = frame.copy()
        orig_frames.append(orig_frame)
        # IMPORTANT STEP: convert the frame to grayscale first
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        if frame_count % consecutive_frame == 0 or frame_count == 1:
            frame_diff_list = []
        # find the difference between current frame and base frame
        frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(gray, background)
        # thresholding to convert the frame to binary
        #ret, thres = cv2.threshold(frame_diff, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        #frame_diff = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame_diff, (3, 3), 0)
        ret, thres = cv2.threshold(frame_diff, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

        cv2.imshow('frame_diff', frame_diff)
        out.write(frame_diff)
        if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        # ... makes the detection of contours a bit easier
        kernel = numpy.ones((9,9), numpy.uint8) # bu gerekli mi
        erode_frame = cv2.erode(thres, kernel, iterations=1) # (thres, None, iterations=1)
        # append the final result into the `frame_diff_list`
        frame_diff_list.append(erode_frame)

        #     cv2.imshow("lines", line_img)
        #     #cv2.imshow("canny", canny_img)
        #     if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        #         break

        # if we have reached `consecutive_frame` number of frames
        if len(frame_diff_list) == consecutive_frame:
            # add all the frames in the `frame_diff_list`
            sum_frames = sum(frame_diff_list)
            # find the contours around the white segmented areas
            contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(sum_frames, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            # draw the contours, not strictly necessary
            for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
                cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, i, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            for contour in contours:
                # continue through the loop if contour area is less than 500...
                # ... helps in removing noise detection
                if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 300:
                    continue
                # get the xmin, ymin, width, and height coordinates from the contours
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                # draw the bounding boxes
                cv2.rectangle(orig_frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                detections.append([x, y, w, h]) ###

            cv2.imshow('Detected Objects', orig_frame)
            out.write(orig_frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: these two pictures are of different points in time, and they're screenshots... please don't give screenshots but save the pictures themselves (imwrite). and make sure they are for the same point in time.

Comment: what is `get_background`? if you have issues with that, it's no longer an OpenCV question. regardless, you must explain what this is. link or source code.

Comment: Those 3 rectangles outside of the bumpers contain noises.. You will have to get rid of them. Using canny, threshold, etc. You will see a small dots for all 3 rectangles.